# Matplotlib colorbar not showing labels for 2 discrete values

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, legend, imshow

With an array of 3 discrete values I can use `imshow` to create a colorbar.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img_data1 = np.random.choice([0,1,2], size=100).reshape((10,10))

plt.imshow(img_data1)
plt.colorbar(ticks = [0,1,2], values = [0,1,2])
```

Produces:
[image]

But if the array only has 2 discrete values, `[0,1]`, the colorbar labels are missing.

```
img_data2 = np.random.choice([0,1], size=100).reshape((10,10))

plt.imshow(img_data2)
plt.colorbar(ticks = [0,1], values = [0,1])
```

Produces:
[image]

How can I make the the color bar with 2 values have ticks marks and labels?

Comment: I tried your code and it does show for me, maybe your fig size is small and the numbers are cut off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code work fine for me:

[image]

I am using matplotlib 3.4.2. Try to update your package if it is not up to date.

---

In any case, you can customize colorbar labels with:

```
cbar = plt.colorbar(ticks = [0,1], values = [0,1])
cbar.ax.get_yaxis().set_ticks([0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1]) # pass the array of labels you want
```

[image]

Comment: That was it. Upgrading matplotlib from 3.1.1 to 3.4.3 fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: In the last code, you can do `cbar.set_ticks([0.25, 0.75])` and `cbar.set_ticklabels([0, 1])` to get the labels similar to the 3-label example. (Also note, you don't need the `cbar.ax.get_yaxis()` part anymore).